# Difference between CFA using WLSMV estimator and IRT

Tags: categorical-data, confirmatory-factor, item-response-theory

I am trying to understand the differences (or similarities) between conducting CFA on categorical data using the WLSMV estimator in SEM and item response theory analysis. I would appreciate any input. Moreover, is there a way to convert Mplus parameters to difficulty and discrimination parameters?

Comment: If you use the ML estimator in Mplus I think that it is the same model (but it's very slow to converge, especially if your model is complex.)

Comment: This paper might help: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/37e3/9037c53773de515b0cc22205f2f64ce468b9.pdf

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for the response and reference. I have also noticed the difference in the estimation time. But I don't think that this is the only difference. Any way I will have a look at the paper.

Comment: IIRC, it's an equivalent model, but parameterized differently you use ML estimation with categorical data in Mplus (but it's a while since I've done this).

Comment: One is typically interested in moving between IRT and CFA parameters when the CFA model treats item responses data as continuous. Both estimation strategies you mention treated item responses as discrete, so I do not see a need for such a conversion.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The conversion will help me to express coefficients in terms of difficulty and discrimation, which reviewers and reader understand better.